# Deleting edge pixels in raster using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, arcgis-10.1

Does anyone know how to delete single edge pixels in a raster after a mask is completed?

I could convert to polygon and back to raster, but I don't want to lose accuracy. I am using ArcMap.

Comment: Have you explored the [Shrink](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/shrink.htm) tool?

Comment: Try region group, it will contain count of pixels.

Comment: Feel free to ask a separate second question about ArcGIS Pro if you want to know how to do it in both applications.

Comment: You should be able to apply some filter, for example convert to numpy array then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46043048/python-numpy-array-close-smallest-regions

Answer (score -1):

Does these pixels all has the same unique value? for example, 0,0,0? 
You can just omit those pixels from your raster.

[image]